# Else part of an if_else condition dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a follow up question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467599/mutate-column-if-column-exists-loop-dplyr/71467917?noredirect=1#comment126322250_71467917)

I want to replace values in `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` according to whether or not column `v3` contains a 1, a 2, or a 3 by group in `v2`.

My goal is to write `Nav` in column `t1` if for a given group of `v2` column `v3` has value 1.

The problem I face comes from the `else` part of the statement. I would like that if in the example above `v3` does not contain 1 that column `t1` stays the same.

Any idea?

```
mutate(across(starts_with("t"), ~if_else(any(v3==i),"NAv", HERE COLUMN REMAINS UNCHANGED)))
```

```
df <- data.frame (v1 = c("Fran", "Fran", "Fran", "Belg", "Belg", "Belg"),
                  v2 = c(1201, 1201, 1202, 1203, 1204, 1205),
                  v3 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1),
                  t1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  t2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  t3 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)


for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- df %>%
    group_by(v2) %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("t"), ~if_else(any(v3==i),"NAv", NULL)))
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your code. Since `df` gets overwritten on every iteration, the ultimate result is equivalent to if you just did `(mutate(across(starts_with("t"), ~ifelse(any(v3 %in% 1:3),"NAv", .x)))` without the `for` loop. With your example, this results in *every* value being changed to `"NAv"`. Is this actually what you want?

Comment: While I think our answers might address the question, I am also very confused by the code: because you are iterating over `i` values of `1:3`, with this sample data the same effect would be seen with a much-simpler `df[4:6] <- "NAv"`. While that over-simplification is obviously over-the-top, it is important to make sure that your sample data is representative enough that it is clear when something *should* happen as well as when it *should not*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems:

1. Your `t*` columns in this sample data are of class `logical`, not `character`, so I'll coerce them in the first `mutate`. (This step may not be necessary with your real data.)
2. You cannot use `NULL` in any portion of an `ifelse`/`if_else`. Since you want to retain the previous value if the condition is not met, then we'll use the `.` placeholder that `across` uses.
3. Using `any(.)` inside the `if_else` collapses the length of the first argument `condition=` will always be seen as length-1; instead, we need to `rep`eat the return from `any(.)` for as many rows as we have, using `rep(.., n())`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("t"), as.character)) %>%
  group_by(v2) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("t"), ~ if_else(rep(any(v3 == 1), n()), "NAv", .) )) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   v1       v2    v3 t1    t2    t3   
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 Fran   1201     1 NAv   NAv   NAv  
# 2 Fran   1201     2 NAv   NAv   NAv  
# 3 Fran   1202     1 NAv   NAv   NAv  
# 4 Belg   1203     1 NAv   NAv   NAv  
# 5 Belg   1204     3 NA    NA    NA   
# 6 Belg   1205     1 NAv   NAv   NAv
```

Answer (score 3):

in `across()`, `.x` stands in for the current column. So:

```
mutate(across(starts_with("t"), ~ifelse(any(v3==i),"NAv", .x)))
```

Comment: With the reproducible example I get the following message... Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(starts_with("t"), ~if_else(any(v3 == i), "NAv", .x))`.
x `false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: v2 = 1201.

Comment: @AnEostig right -- `dplyr::if_else()` is strict about conditions being the same length as outputs, so doesn't like that `any(v3 == i)` is length 1 but `.x` isn't. You can get around this by using `base::ifelse()` instead. I've edited my answer to do this.